# Is there algorithm / software / library that can plot graph (without knowing coordinates) onto a grid?

Tags: plot, graph

I have files containing graphs generated on grid looking like this:

- (connected n6 n0)
- (connected n0 n6)
- (= (distance n6 n0) 1)
- (=(distance n0 n6) 1)
- (connected n0 n4)
- (connected n4 n0)
- (= (distance n0 n4) 1)
- (= (distance n4 n0) 1)
- (connected n4 n7)
- (connected n7 n4)
- (= (distance n4 n7) 2)
- (= (distance n7 n4) 2)
- ...

or if it would be possible for graph looking like this:

- (connected loc-1 loc-0)
- (connected loc-1 loc-17)
- (connected loc-1 loc-2)

where we know that, loc-1 is connected to 2 nodes of higher id -> loc-**2**, loc-**17** so loc-2 has to be (depending on orientation) right to it and loc-17 over it.

[looking like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38qjB.png)

and i need to plot them onto a grid.
I tried using networkx  but force-based generated graphs are not anywhere close to grid and i haven't been able to find any library / program able to do this without knowing coordinates of nodes.

Comment: " loc-2, loc-17 so loc-2 has to be (depending on orientation) right to it and loc-17 over it." Why does this *have* to be?  What is the logic that makes the conclusion follow from the input?

Comment: Because we are on grid, and id of node "corresponds" to their location (so node 0 is guaranteed to be at (0, 0) coordinates) for this type of grahp, for the first one i posted this rule doesnt apply, the problem here is that node can be connected to higher id node (e.g. loc-1 -> loc-17), but if its just one, there could be gaps, so that wont guarantee it is above it.

Comment: You need to edit your question to describe this logic.  At present, your question makes no sense.

Comment: How exactly does node is correspond to location?  It doesn't seem possible.  The node is is a single integer.  The location is a pair of integers.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.